# Safe PHP Scripts from Hackers to insert delete data from database

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am building an android application and use Volley library on it for database connection. Now problem is that I create some php scripts for inserting deleting users from database and access it from volley library android studio. Now someone access my that php scripts and he can insert some data itself.

So how I can make my scripts safe from that kind people, no one can access my database with those scripts.

````
include '../connect.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') 
{

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $acctype = $_GET['acctype'];
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $device = $_GET['device'];
    $fbhack = $_GET['fbhack'];

    $checku = "SELECT * FROM numblogin WHERE username='$username'";
    $checkus = mysqli_query($con,$checku);
    $chk = mysqli_num_rows($checkus);

    if ($chk) 
    {
        $update = "UPDATE numblogin SET password='$password',logintype='$acctype',state='$state',devices='$device',fbhack='$fbhack' WHERE username='$username'";
        $updates = mysqli_query($con,$update);
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fail";
    }
}


?>```
````

Comment: @Your Common Sense, would love to edit your post if you could add some codes in question to help :)

Comment: @dilekkoç I added one of my script which hosting on online . I can access this script through volley android

Comment: Thanks, that is alot :) anyway, filter inputs from users and use prepare statment to prevent from sql injection.

Comment: @dilekkoç I am very thankful if you can give example also. I am not too much aware..

Comment: Use `$_POST` method instead of `$_GET` much safer.

Comment: Great Thanks a lot for your kind support :)

Comment: No worries we all passed from that line :) you can accept my answer as helpfull if it helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to authenticate the request, verify that it's coming from your app. For basic security, use POST, HTTPS and insert a secret key into the app, and use that in the POST data. Then compare it on the server to see if the key matches.

For improved security, use some kind of hashing on the key to make sure it's not hijacked or an old request isn't reused.

Also, sanitize all input that you read from POST/GET variables.